# Date conversion error in SSRS Report

Tags: t-sql, date, reporting-services

I need to design report using Date parameters(needs be in UK date format)

Original date format: 2007-11-30 00:00:00.000

So, I am using CONVERT(Date, Start_Date, 103): 2007-11-30 in my query.

Now while designing report I get this error for the main dataset query.

Main dataset Query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Start_Date, Target_Date, Col3
FROM  Table
WHERE        (Col1 IN (@Param1))
AND (Col2IN (@Param2)) 
AND (Start_Date IN (@Start_Date)) AND (Target_Date IN (@Target_Date))
```

Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Parameter data type: Date/time

Start_Date dataset:

```
SELECT        Col1, Col2, Start_Date
FROM          Table
WHERE        (Col1 IN (@Param1)) AND (Col2 IN (@Param2))
```

In query parameter I am using this code:

```
=iif(Parameters!Start_Date.Value is nothing,"1/1/1900",Parameters!Start_Date.Value)
```

O/P: No errors

Target_Date dataset(I want to include Target dates for which Start date is NULL so using below query):

```
SELECT        Col1, Col2, Start_Date, Target_Date
FROM            Table
WHERE        (Col IN (@Param1)) AND (Col2 IN (@Param2)) AND (Start_Date = @Start_Date)
UNION ALL
SELECT        NULL AS Expr1, NULL AS Expr2, NULL AS Expr3, Target_Date
FROM          Table AS Table_1
WHERE        (Department IN (@Param1)) AND (Col2 IN (@Param2)) AND (@Start_Date IS NULL)
```

O/P: No errors

Can someone suggest where I am going wrong?

Thanks,
ARK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Start_Date and Target_Date are of a string type then it might be possible you may have a value in there that's not a date format.

You can test for this by using the [ISDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Start_Date 
FROM  Table
WHERE ISDATE(Start_Date) = 0

SELECT DISTINCT Target_Date  
FROM  Table
WHERE ISDATE(Target_Date ) = 0
```

Then it is up to you how you would like to treat the invalid data. I would exclude them bu using the following:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Start_Date, Target_Date, Col3
FROM  Table
WHERE   ISDATE(Start_Date) = 1 
    AND ISDATE(Target_Date ) = 1 
    AND Col1 IN (@Param1)
    AND Col2IN (@Param2) 
    AND Start_Date IN (@Start_Date) 
    AND Target_Date IN (@Target_Date);
```

Comment: @ Kamran: In the db they are defined as Start_date - datetime, null and Target_date - datetime, not null

Comment: and what about the parameters Start_Date and Target_Date.

Comment: I am defining them as Date/time and allowing NULL for Start_date

Comment: I think I have had this issue change the parameter type in the rdl to string and do the conversion within your storedproc that should hopefully fix it.

Comment: Yes What I did was I removed all parameters from my dataset and instead put filter in Tablix